# Create public functions on a WordPress site (API behaviour)

Tags: wordpress

Is that possible to create public function that we could access from another site, like a "custom API" on a WordPress site ?

For example, URL "my-wordpress.com/my_function" would return the code defined in my_function().

Thanks for answers,
Sébastien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XMLRPC interface provided by WordPress.

See these links:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support
- http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending

This might be the right way to offer a custom API, but it doesn't allow you to simply call a function using a URL. Communication is done via XML that you send to the xmlrpc.php in your wordpress root.